# How does a selection logic for Conway's Game of Life work?

Tags: digital-logic

In this [implementation of Conway's Game of Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mglYNBcLKlM), they talk about using two layers of PIPO shift registers to select the the current and surrounding cells. I can think of somethings like this:

Suppose the cells are:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Then the there are three arrays of input, i.e. `25 21 22 23 24 25 21` (extra entries for wrap around), `5 1 2 3 4 5 1` and `10 6 7 8 9 10 6`

Let the logic work on first three cells of each  of arrays, i.e. on `25 21 22, 5 1 2, 10 6 7` to get the ouput of 1 and latch using D-flip flop and so on.

I believe in some way we could shift the rows altogether from 5th 1st 2nd to now 1st 2nd and 3rd using another shift registers maybe?

Note that the logic unit can be implemented fairly easily and I have already made one so it is no big problem.

There has to be some way to not make 25 logic units (each 8-9 ic's).
What do you people think?

I have also thought about using some shift logic like [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-24X6-LED-matrix/) which looks very promising with a decade counter for the rows.

Comment: Are you limited to logic ICs? Because this screams for using a lookup table implemented in one 512x1 bit EPROM. Using a ingenious adressing scheme, you probably could lookup 8 cells at once, using one 4k x 8 bit EPROM or similar.

Comment: Yes logical ic's... Basic gates and shifter and some 7400s ttl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they're doing is probably something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fepFCK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current state of the game is held in U2. One at a time, 9 cells are evaluated and the new state for the center cell is generated and loaded into U1. Both registers are shifted to the right one place to evaluate the next set of cells. Note that U2 is connected to recirculate the data during this phase. After 25 clocks, the new state for the entire game is in U1, and a parallel transfer from U1 to U2 then makes this new state the current state.

The DIP switches for the initial state are probably connected to the parallel inputs of U1. The LEDs are connected to the outputs of U2, and the game is paused after every 25-clock update cycle so that you can see the results of each step. The "speed" control is really just controlling the length of the pause.

Comment: I'm guessing the speed control is just a potentiometer used to set the frequency of a 555 timer used to generate the main clock. The delay to observe the current state is used to generate the next state.

Comment: @ThePhoton: No, you can't update and display at the same time using my block diagram. That would require a third register to hold the display state. I'm guessing that they use a fairly fast (constant) master clock, and simply trigger update cycles using either a pushbutton or a 555.

Comment: lots of shift register ICs have two layers of registers in them.

Comment: Also, your diagram is too small to read any of the text on it, even if I "open image in new tab".

Comment: @ThePhoton: You probably need to open it in the CircuitLab editor. Click "simulate this circuit" -- although it isn't actually able to be simulated.

Comment: @ThePhoton: chips with "two layers" still have only one set of outputs. We'd need access to both layers for this application. Although I guess you could use '595 type registers for U1, since the parallel outputs are only needed once per update. But then you wouldn't have the parallel-load option for the initial state.

Comment: You are probably right. The last time I did a discrete logic project as big as the one in the video was one class in college, so I certainly don't know all the available MSI parts and their capabilities. Nowadays lay down a CPLD and be done with it.

Comment: This worked.. But the neighbour logic is wrong. I fixed it and it worked in Logisim. Thankyou so much.